# Construct flame graph from trie

Tags: python, algorithm, trie, flamegraph

I have some stats in a trie which is generated periodically. I want to generate flame graphs on the difference between two tries. How do I do that?

```
t = pygtrie.StringTrie(separator=os.path.sep)

for dirpath, unused_dirnames, filenames in os.walk(ROOT_DIR):
    for filename in filenames:
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        try:
            filestat = os.stat(filename)
        except OSError:
            continue
        if stat.S_IFMT(filestat.st_mode) == stat.S_IFREG:
            t[filename] = filestat.st_size
```

Comment: But wait, why do you expect trie difference to be a flame graph? The only thing that can possibly become a flame graph is trie intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the diff. But you can draw flame graph on files (or anything else if you produce the similar output) using [FlameGraph tool](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph).

Here is a topic from the author of this tool about how to make [Flame graphs for file systems](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-02-05/file-system-flame-graph.html). Using this tool you need just execute following command to get chart.

```sh
./files.pl /Users | ./flamegraph.pl --hash --countname=bytes > out.svg
```

Here is similar tool - [duviz](https://github.com/soxofaan/duviz), that creates similar chart, but for CLI not as an image output. Pros - it is written in Python.